# RequireJS fallback if CDN is not available

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, requirejs, cdn

I have reference requirejs in my website

now I want to have a fallback in case CDN is not available

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.0.6/require.min.js" data-main="@Url.Content("~/scripts/application")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Something like this in jQuery

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.5.1.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
```

It should also run without dependency in jQuery all other libraries.

Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

```
<script data-main="js/main" src="//requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.14/minified/require.js"></script>
<script>if(!window.define || !window.define.amd) document.write('<script data-main="js/main" src="js/libs/require.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
```